# Reorder title tag and description tag with wpseo_title and wpseo_metadesc

Tags: title, plugin-wp-seo-yoast, wp-title, description

I'm trying to change the order of the title tag and description tag (CMS Wordpress, plugin Yoast SEO). Now in the code of the page it looks like this:

```
<title>something ...</title>
<meta name="description" content="something ..."/>
```

And I want to do this:

```
<meta name="description" content="something ..."/>
<title>something ...</title>
```

I tried this snippet in function.php, but this code does not work correctly

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_title', '__return_false' );

add_filter( 'wpseo_title', 'filter_wpseo_title', 90);

add_filter( 'wpseo_metadesc', '__return_false' );

add_filter( 'wpseo_metadesc', 'filter_wpseo_title', 10);
```

Comment: You can ask this in Yoast plugin's forum.

Comment: Any reason why you want to do this?